# Move OneNote "Unfiled Notes" section out of noteook?

Tags: microsoft-onenote-2007

I accidentally moved my "Unfiled Notes" section into my "Work Notebook".  Everything still functions appropriately, but how do I get the section *out* of my "Work Notebook"?

Answer (score 0):

I found there answer [here](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/29973262/unfiled-notes-tab.aspx).

Basically you move the file back to One Note's root (under my documents), then modify the setting under Options / Save to point to the file's new location.